# How can I locate the correct element using querySelector

Tags: javascript

In chrome console, i am able to inject a js like below

```
$("#pageForm").window('open');
```

And then the DIV form will pop up, however, if i change it to below

```
document.querySelector("div#pageForm").window('open');
```

It will return error: *Uncaught TypeError: document.querySelector(...).window is not a function
    at :1:41*

Am I doing wrong in locating an element ?
Thanks

Comment: $().window seems to be a function that some jQuery Plugin exposes, this is not vanilla JS, so you can't use it without a jQuery Object.

Comment: to be clear `window()` isn't even standard jQuery, so, you'll have to give us a clue as to where that jquery function is coming from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply wrap the queryselctor with $

```
$(document.querySelector("div#pageForm")).window('open');
```

Answer (score 1):

The `window` method you're calling - whatever that is - is a method that is provided to jQuery by a plugin you're using. It doesn't seem as though jQuery has a `window` method out of the box. Because you're using a jQuery plugin you need to locate your element using jQuery instead of a query selector.

Answer (score 1):

that `$` (dollar sign) you use is jQuery. (It may not be exactly every-day jQuery, it might be something chrome made up for pages that have not jQuery)

there is a difference between the result of `$('<some_selector>')` & `document.querySelector('<some_selector>')`; the first one returns a javascript object, which is a wrapper around the DOM Node found in the HTML. this wrapper object has some methods on it (including `height()`, `width()`, `show()`, `window()`, etc...) which may be added by jQuery or it's plugins (as suggested by Dwight). But the second way (`document.querySelector`) returns a DOMNode. it is a regular DOM Node and no! it has not a `window()` method on it

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I agree with answer above. It seems you correctly select the element. However, window property does not belong js out of the box. Its gotta be a jquery plugin so that you can use with jquery. Another function made available to jquery.

Comment: does it offer something in addition to current answer? If yes, then specify it explcitly

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.